# How to validate local admin credentials against a set of servers

Tags: powershell

I have 60 servers, VMs to be particular. And I have a local admin username and password. Instead of logging on to 60 servers using these local admin creds, it would be better if there is a script to check if I could log on to these servers as a local admin using the local admin creds. To be precise, I want to check.if I can use this local admin creds to successfully log on to all 60 VMs.

I have googled but no luck. I know stackoverflow is not a place to directly ask for a piece of code, but in this case I am forced to. Even if you dont have a direct answer please direct me somewhere.

```
gc serverlist.txt | % {
    $admin_share = '\\' + $_ + '\admin$'
    if (Test-Path $admin_share) {
        Write-Host "Access test passed on $($_)"
    } else {
        Write-Host "Access test failed on $($_)"
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried... *anything*?

Comment: No I haven't, I have a piece of code with me. I have added that to my main post, please recommend.

Comment: Nope, that wouldn't work. It will user your current sessions' context, not the local admin account on the remote server. Are you familiar with `net use`?

Comment: Aside: This is one of the purposes of a domain (not having to manage multiple sets of credentials for individual machines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a variation of your attempt.
It assumes the same username and password for all computers.

```
#Get list of cserver names from file
$Servers = Get-Content -Path  serverlist.txt
#Prompt user foe credentials
$Cred = Get-Credential 

foreach ($Svr in $Servers)
{
    #path to share (\\ServerName\Admin$)
    $Path = '\\' + $Svr + '\Admin$'

    Try
    {
        #Map admin share as PS Drive (NOT visable in the GUI) 
        #ErrorAction stop will jump to catch block if the connection is unsuccessfull
        New-PSDrive -Name TEST -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $Path  -Credential $Cred -ErrorAction Stop

        #Success Message
        Write-Output "Connection Successful $Svr"

        #Remove drive before next loop
        Remove-PSDrive -Name TEST
    }

    Catch
    {
        #Error message if connection fails
        Write-Warning -Message "Connect failed $Svr"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have ICMP enabled, you could use Test-Connection cmdlet with the Credential switch. You can see more details in example 3 here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-connection?view=powershell-6